# Can fusors be used to turn Uranium 238 into Plutonium 239?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Since a  Farnsworth–Hirsch fusor is apparently a [good fast neutron source](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph241/klopfer2/) that is simple enough to [build at home](https://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/nuclear-fusor/), why can't it be used by rogue states or even terrorists to turn non fissile U-238, depleted Uranium that the US often shoots [*at* its enemies](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2000/may/18/armstrade.kosovo) in the form of shells, into fissile Plutonium-239 through neutron bombardment?

I'm assuming that the neutron output from such a device would only be enough to create a microscopic amount of plutonium and therefore wouldn't be useful, but I was wondering what other physical constraints prevent this from being a proliferation threat.

Comment: For high neutron flux, use a spallation neutron source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fusor emits $10^7$ neutrons/sec. One being developed hopefully will emit $10^{11}$ neutrons/sec.

Compare that to $6 \times 10^{23}$ atoms/mole.

Comment: And also , add cross section  of the reaction to obtain 239Pu from 238U  .

Comment: As @JeanJacques indicates, fast neutrons are not the way to go to get 239U - the cross section above 1MeV i roughly 6 orders of magnitude smaller than the thermal neutron cross section.

Comment: @JeanJacques An update: https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/phoenix-completes-milestone-test-with-unprecedented-neutron-output-and-reliability-300871003.html Curiously, on the Wikipedia page, the maximum output of the fusor reactors is frozen at the 2013 record.